# laravel database query max(date) getting all posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.4, where i try to get the latest post, but for some reason if I want to select the title, I end up getting them all, can someone explain me, why I get all posts when I use

```
$latest = Post::selectRaw('title, max(created_at), body as MaxDate')
        ->groupBy('title', 'MaxDate')
        ->get();
```

but when I use

```
$latest = Post::selectRaw('user_id, max(created_at), body as MaxDate')
        ->groupBy('user_id', 'MaxDate')
        ->get();
```

I only get the latest post. Why does it mess up, if I wish to select the title? :/

Comment: use `first()` instead of `get()`

Comment: it worked, but I wanted to get it to work with a sql query :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in your first example, you are saying to MySQL: "for each title and each body, give me the max creation date", which most likely will be the only creation date for that title / body combination.

In other words, you're grouping for something (the title and body), but in all the groups you generate you're not aggregating anything, because the creation date will be different for each group.

I don't know Laravel, but if what you want is getting the title of the latest post, the SQL query to do that is

```
select  title
from    yourTable
where   created_at = (
            select  max(created_at)
            from    yourTable
        )
```

If you want the title of the latest post of each user instead, the query would be

```
select  user_id, title
from    yourTable t1
join    (
            select  user_id, max(created_at) as created_at
            from    yourTable
            group by user_id
        ) t2
on      t1.user_id = t2.user_id and
        t1.created_at = t2.created_at
```